# Unsigned int or bigint primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need use unsigned int or bigint primary key in one of my mysql tables. 
How can i do it? 
I need to store this info in `schema.rb` too.

Comment: Rails adds int primary key by default to every table you create with migration.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions